# How to apply empirical Bayes to multi-class classification?

Tags: bayesian, empirical-bayes

We can use an empirical Bayes framework to iteratively refine the least-squares fitting of some model $f$ parameterized by weights $\textbf{w}$. This can be done by presuming a Gaussian prior on the residuals and a Gaussian prior on the weights (mean 0 with some variances $\sigma_r^2,\sigma_\textbf{w}^2$, respectively). Then iteratively:

1. Find and set MAP values for $\textbf{w}$ assuming $\sigma_r,\sigma_\textbf{w}$ are fixed (with the $i$-th residual $r_i=y_i-f_{\textbf{w}}(\textbf{x}_i)$)
   $$
   \frac{1}{2\sigma_r^2}\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^2+\frac{1}{2\sigma_\textbf{w}^2}\left\|\textbf{w}\right\|^2
   $$
2. Find and set MAP values for $\sigma_r,\sigma_\textbf{w}$ assuming $r_i,\textbf{w}$ are fixed (i.e., fit 0-mean Gaussians).

Is there an analogous procedure for cross entropy loss? If we operate on (multiclass) logistic deviance residuals, is there an appropriate prior distribution to select for them? It doesn't make sense to make them Gaussian.